# John Carter's Return To Earth

Tags: john-carter

In the movie "John Carter," as opposed to the novel, "A Princess Of Mars," when Carter wakes up in the cave, back on Earth, why is he wearing the clothes that he wore to Mars, have a beard, and covered with dust? In order to be consistent with the premise of his travel to and from Mars, he should have returned smooth shaven and wearing his Barsoomian clothes.

Answer (score 7):

When he teleported to Mars, only his soul travelled to Mars and his body on Mars was a copy of the original one he left behind on Earth.

When he was returned to Earth, his soul teleported from Mars back to his original body on Earth (and into his old clothes).  That copy of his body, because it's just a copy, would have disappeared on Mars.